# What replicates the benefits of 'Silk Armor' to Heal checks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, armor, healing

There are historical references to wearing silk under armor. If the silk is loose enough, arrows bind in it rather than break through. The benefit of this is that the arrow's barbs are covered by the silk, allowing the head to be pulled back out of the wound, causing less damage than other treatment methods.

What items replicate this, and what are their specs or properties? On the old *Wizards of the Coast* website, there was something about a +2 to heal checks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### No *official* silk or silklike armors grant a bonus to Heal skill checks

That include armors made from actual silk:

- silk armor (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 116; originally *Dragon* #298 50) (5,000 gp; 15 lbs.)
- silk swathes (*Sandstorm* 99) (400 gp; 6 lbs.)
- twisted silk (*Dragon* #348 87) (400 gp; 15 lbs.)

*And* that includes armors made from things *called* silk:

- shadowsilk hide (*Tome of Magic* 155) (2,500 gp; 5.5 lbs.)
- shadowsilk leather (*Tome of Magic* 155) (1,750 gp; 4 lbs.)
- shadowsilk padded (*Tome of Magic* 155) (1,500 gp; 2.5 lbs.)
- spidersilk armor (*Underdark* 66, *Shadowdale: Scouring of the Land* 149) (750 gp; 5 lbs.) ([No, not this one.](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=19870))

All such armors are light armors, but spidersilk armor is an *exotic* light armor, requiring a separate feat for proficiency with it. (The armor's armor check penalty is only −1 though, so making it masterwork means not really needing the proficiency.)

---

***Note:*** If third-party material is allowed, this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87316/8610) has you covered.

Answer (score 17):

You are thinking of the silk shirt from Mongoose Publishing's "[Ultimate Equipment Guide Volume 1](http://www.mongoosepublishing.com/ultimate-equipment-guide.html)." It's not armor, it's just a shirt, and it does give a +2 circumstance bonus to Heal checks to heal damage caused by a ranged piercing weapon.

> Shirt, Silk: 28 gp; 1 lb.